# Django Type Error No Exception Supplied

Tags: python, django, django-models

HI Here is my code for comparing two mobiles technical specifications

```
def getFormValues(request):
    if ('mobile_a' in request.GET and request.GET['mobile_a']) and ('mobile_b' in request.GET and request.GET['mobile_b']):
        mobile_a = request.GET['mobile_a']
        mobile_b =request.GET['mobile_b']
        # calling the mark calculation function
        return calculateMark(mobile_a, mobile_b)

    else:
        message ='You submitted an empty form.'
        return HttpResponse(message)

def calculateMark(mobile_a, mobile_b):
    #variables
    mobile_a = mobile_a
    mobile_b = mobile_b
    tech_mark_a= 0
    tech_mark_b = 0

    results_a = []
    results_b = []

    record_a = TechSpecificationAdd.objects.filter(mobile_name=mobile_a).values()
    record_b = TechSpecificationAdd.objects.filter(mobile_name=mobile_a).values()

    results_a += record_a
    results_b += record_b

    #dimension
    if int(record_a["dimension"]) > int(record_b["dimension"]):
        tech_mark_a = 1
    else:
        tech_mark_b = 1


    #body-material

    #weight
    if record_a["weight"] > record_b["weight"]:
        tech_mark_b += 1
    else:
        tech_mark_a += 1

    #camera
    if record_a["camera"] > record_b["camera"]:
        tech_mark_a += 1
    else:
        tech_mark_b += 1

    #flash
    if (record_a["flash"]):
        tech_mark_a += 1
    if (record_b["flash"]):
        tech_mark_b += 1

    #video
    if record_a["video"] > record_b["video"]:
        tech_mark_a += 1
    else:
        tech_mark_b += 1

    #fps
    if record_a["fps"] > record_b["fps"]:
        tech_mark_a += 1
    else:
        tech_mark_b += 1

    #front-camera
    if record_a["front_camera"] > record_b["front_camera"]:
        tech_mark_a += 1
    else:
        tech_mark_b += 1


    return render_to_response('degrees_result.html', {'data_a': results_a, 'data_b': results_b})
```

In this situation django debug is showing the error "TypeError at /calculate_mark/
No exception supplied". If you ask for Traceback infos then I can provide.

So What is the problem? I could't figure out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[QuerySet.values](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values) returns `ValuesQuerySet` object (which is similar to list of dictionaries)

```
record_a = TechSpecificationAdd.objects.filter(mobile_name=mobile_a).values()
```

But the code is using it as if it is a dictionary:

```
int(record_a["dimension"])
```

---

Convert such usage as follow:

```
int(record_a[0]["dimension"])
```

or convert `record_a` as dictionary:

```
record_a = record_a[0]
```